# How to get smooth thick lines in SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

How can I draw smooth looking lines and specify their thickness using SDL2. Currently I am limited to this type of line quality:

[image]

and to a width of 1 pixel.

I have tried `SDL_RenderSetScale` paired with `SDL_SetHint` to get a bigger line and hoping to retain detail, but it doesn't work nicely or well in the slightest (actually looks worse).

What can I do to get a function such as `SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, x1, y1, x2, y2)` that allows me to specify width and maintains quality such as is possible via text using `SDL_RenderText_Blended` compared to `SDL_RenderText_Solid`, assuming my lines are currently the "Solid" and I want the quality to be that of the "Blended"?

Comment: ```SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode()``` ? Just from a quick perusal of the SDL docs. And perhaps one of the ```SDL_BlendMode```'s does what you want.

Comment: Ah, I should have added that to the question. I have that on.